# Containerised Web Application which connects to Relational DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, containers, amazon-ecs

Can anyone point me in the direction of some demo code/app that I can use for a demo.
The app should have the ability to connect to a relational database and ideally be able to demonstrate the persistence of having the DB.

I.e. You can save values into the DB from the web app

I'm planning to deploy this onto AWS ECS for testing, alongside RDS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is an AWS tutorial that shows how to write a Java Spring Boot Web app that is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk ( Elastic Beanstalk is an AWS service that leverages Amazon EC2 and S3 and deploys, manages and scales your web applications for you. It uses managed containers that support Node. js, Java, Ruby, Docker and more) and uses RDS to store and update data.

[Creating the Amazon Relational Database Service item tracker](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker)

So most of what you are looking for is there - including how to setup the RDS instance and interact with it from a web app deployed to the cloud. If you follow this step by step (there is a lot of Java code) -- you will get this Sample Web App running on the cloud and it will teach you how to interact with RDS from a web app.

[image]

Also - this covers invoking additional services such as **Simple Email Service** from the web app.